# Draw 3D grid using AC3?

Tags: arrays, flash, grid, action

[This is what I want it to look like... check the link](http://postimage.org/image/3ot3j85l9/)

I'm trying to create a grid like this for a game I'm working on.
any idea how this can be done using AC3?

[This is how it looks like now... check the link](http://postimage.org/image/cqjuu6cdx/)

this is how it looks now basically I want to morph it into a 3d grid.
this is my coding for what I've done:

```
function generateField():void

var colors:Array = new Array("0xCCCCCC","0x666666");
fieldArray = new Array();
var fieldSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(fieldSprite);
fieldSprite.graphics.lineStyle(0,0x000000);
for (var i:uint=0; i<20; i++)
{
    fieldArray[i] = new Array();
    for (var j:uint=0; j<10; j++)
    {
        fieldArray[i][j] = 0;
        fieldSprite.graphics.beginFill(colors[(j%2+i%2)%2]);
        fieldSprite.graphics.drawRect(TS*j,TS*i,TS,TS);
        fieldSprite.graphics.endFill();
    }
}
```

Your help is much appreciated.